# how to calculate ETA between two points

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a situation where I have to find all nearest hotels within 3km and show their distance and estimated time for given location.

my code to fetch all nearest hotels around 3km.

```
Hotels.geoNear({
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [userLat, userLng]
}, {
  spherical: true,
  maxDistance: 3000,
  distanceMultiplier: 0.001
}).then(function(hotels) {
  console.log(hotels);
});
```

Here I am able to get distance for all object, but i don't have any idea how to get estimated time for each location.

Any suggestion how can I find estimated time for each location?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use historical data for each location. For example to save in your database how long it took for user1 to get from location1 to location2 and when user2 goes on the same route, then calculate the ETA based on that data.

However, if you don't have access to historical data then use some constant speed values, for example:

- avg. speed with car in city **35km/h**
- avg. speed on foot **5km/h**
- avg. speed with bike in city **20km/h**
- avg. speed with public transportation **30km/h**

Knowing these values:

`eta_in_minutes = (distance_in_km * 60) / constant_estimated_speed_in_km_per_h`

Please note that these are just my estimations, they might not be very accurate, so just play with these values to find out which one fits your needs best.

Comment: yes getting historical data is not possible. These constant will help me to find approximate ETA. 
Is there any other way to integrate this with google api? so I can get actual ETA which google shows on map.

Comment: Yes, here is the solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331309/extracting-trip-eta-from-google-maps-api-possible

Comment: Thanks will look at it.