# How can I get the estimated time of arrival of a vehicle to your current location in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, time

I am creating an application where I can track a nearby busses. I would want to know if is it possible to have an ETA of the bus to your current location

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in APIs could help you, you must use a paid service such as Google direction APIs or , you can refer to this question

[Extracting trip ETA from Google Maps API possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331309/extracting-trip-eta-from-google-maps-api-possible)